# array spliting based on our requirement

Tags: javascript

My array contains the values with comma as separator, like

```
array={raju,rani,raghu,siva,stephen,varam}.
```

But i want to convert into the below format like

```
array = {raju:rani raghu:siva atephen:varam}.
```

please give some logic to implement this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you're starting with a string, you can split it upon comma:

```
var myString = 'raju,rani,raghu,siva,stephen,varam';
var array = myString.split(',');
```

Given that, you can do the following:

```
var array = [ 'raju', 'rani', 'raghu', 'siva', 'stephen', 'varam' ];
var result = {};

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i+= 2) {
   result[array[i]] = array[i+1];
}
```

... which gives the answer you've requested.

Keep in mind that if the array is not evenly divisible by 2, the value of the last item will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to convert array to key-value pair of objects (odd-index is key, even-index is value in the resulting key-value pairs)

```
var array = ['raju', 'rani', 'raghu','siva','stephen','varam'], 
    pairs = {};

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    pairs [array[i]] = array[i + 1];
}
```